# Smart Contract usecases have disappeared from Stellar website / Fixed Term Deposit

Tags: smart-contract

I need infomation about the abilities of Stellar Smart Contract. Unfortunately, this section has disappeared on Stellar Website.

Someone can confirm to me the creation of fixed term deposit is supported ? And How to do that ? :)

I have found this :

**https://github.com/stellar-deprecated/docs/blob/master/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.md**

Comment: That is the only dev doc that explains how to create something like smart contracts on Stellar using protocol features.  Some of the examples need updating, and we will replace it with more current info soon.  In the mean time, I think you may be able to figure out how to create a "fixed-term deposit" using multi-sig and timebounds.  Basically a variation of the first example in the doc.  Thoughts?